# EasyNetQ not reading messages from queue published with RabbitMQ Java Client API

Tags: c#, java, .net, rabbitmq, easynetq

We are using Coldfusion utilising the java RabbitMQ Client API to publish messages to a Queue, and then using EasyNetQ to read the messages from the queue using C#.

The message is a string.

The java Client is publishing messages as an unseralized bytearray with a content-type of text/plain.

When we try and read the message from the queue we always get a EasyNetQ.EasyNetQInvalidMessageTypeException thrown, no matter the type of the message as defined on the EasyNetQ side.  I have tried it as byte array and just a basic object.  I think  EasyNetQ is expecting a serialized object every time?

The exception we are getting is

> Message:
>       2344462
>       BasicProperties:
>       (content-type=text/plain, content-encoding=*, headers=*, delivery-mode=1, priori
>       ty=0, correlation-id=*, reply-to=*, expiration=*, message-id=*, timestamp=*, typ
>       e=*, user-id=*, app-id=*, cluster-id=_)
>
> Exception:
>       EasyNetQ.EasyNetQInvalidMessageTypeException: Message type is incorrect. Expecte
>       d 'System_Byte[]:mscorlib', but was ''

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

EasyNetQ expects a JSON serialized UTF-8 body representing the .NET type given in the subscription method and the 'type' field of basic properties to be populated with a EasyNetQ style type description.

You should use the Advanced API if you want to do your own de-serialization.